# Axios returning HTML from API

Tags: javascript, axios

Feel like I'm being an idiot - 
I have the following code:

```
Axios
  .get('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee/2')
  .then((result) => console.log(result));
```

It's a test API I found online - go ahead and stick that in your browser - it just returns a JSON sample.

When doing calling this through axios like above, the result returned by Axios is a HTML webpage including scripts and all.

What am I missing? Why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: Does the REST endpoint actually return JSON? If so, you need to provide the appropriate headers e.g. `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: Verify request headers contain `Accept: application/json`.  Verify response headers contain `Content-Type: application/json`.

Comment: Request headers contain application/json but response headers do not, it's like my browser is returning a result different to the one returned by axios.

Comment: @imjared It's not what is at the endpoint - see the screenshot

Comment: I'm seeing HTML when I visit the URL you posted in the browser.  However, if you navigate to the API URL from restapiexample.com it checks one of your cookies to conditionally provide the JSON response when you revisit that URL.  If you go incognito you'll see HTML if you visit that URL directly.

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting to convert response to json object:

```
Axios
  .get('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee/2')
  .then(result => result.json())
  .then((result) => console.log(result));
```

Comment: So `Axios.get` is just a fancy way to say `fetch`?

Comment: The response isn't actually a JSON object it's a HTML one with <HTML> tags etc, it fails to convert the object.